# finding unknown CRC 32 bit algorithm used in a firmware file

Tags: crc, firmware-analysis

I want to modify a firmware image for a WiFi router. The image file consist of an UBI image, 0x04100000 bytes in size. Additonally, 20 bytes of unknown metadata have been appended to the UBI image data. I have two different official firmware files for this router. After comparing those 20 bytes of both files I am convinced now that the first 4 bytes are a 32 bit CRC of some sort.

Because CRC32 is very common, I tried CRC32 with various common start values and polynominals without luck. I applied it only across the UBI data before those 20 bytes, the UBI data with the remaining 16 bytes and the UBI data with the whole 20 bytes while using a 0x00000000 and 0xffffffff placeholder for the CRC.

[image]

What could I try next? Is there a way to programatically find CRC32 start values/polynominals when the data and CRC are given?

Here are the files: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15n_Pg8zeSOf_VCcflWoTaMm8MwxBaFXk/view?usp=drive_link

Decompiling the Broadcom CFE bootloader that installs the firmware would be an option but isn't going to be easy at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OK my question didn't age well. Turns out "RevEng" was the tool I needed:

```
reveng.exe -w 32 -fs 010139.3.4.001.0-dec-crc.bin
reveng.exe: warning: you have only given 1 sample
reveng.exe: warning: to reduce false positives, give 4 or more samples
width=32  poly=0x04c11db7  init=0xffffffff  refin=true  refout=true  xorout=0x00000000  check=0x340bc6d9  residue=0x00000000  name="CRC-32/JAMCRC"
```

The input file for RevEng contained the UBI image data plus the 4 bytes CRC appended to the end (thats what RevEng expects).

Comment: You can accept this as an answer.